# multiplying a (N,N) matrix with a vector (V), so that the output is of the shape (N,N,V)

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

Hei there - I'm a python beginner and I'd like to figure out the following:

I want to multiply a matrix of shape (n,n) with a vector of shape (v), so that the output has the shape (n,n,v).

My code looks something like this but it's far from elegant.

```
def D(x,y,B,n): 
    # shape of x,y is (n,n) # shape of B is (v)

    a = np.ndarray(shape = (n,n,1), dtype = float)
    b = np.ndarray(shape = (n,n,1), dtype = float)

    a = np.arctan2(y, x)*(B[0])/(2.*math.pi)    
    b = np.arctan2(y, x)*(B[1])/(2.*math.pi)
    c, d = ...

    return np.asarray([a,b,c,d]).T
```

x and y are the matrices of a meshgrid and represent a radius.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: If `M` is (n,n) and `V` is (v,), `M[:,:,None]*V` will be (n,n,v).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
def D(x,y,B,n): 
    # shape of x,y is (n,n) # shape of B is (v)

```
a = np.ndarray(shape = (n,n,1), dtype = float)
b = np.ndarray(shape = (n,n,1), dtype = float)

c = np.arctan2(y, x) * B[None, None, :]
# c.shape == (n, n, v)


return c.T
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this, this is the fastest method i know

```py
def D(x,y,B,n): 

    M = np.arctan2(y, x)          # shape= [n, n]
    b = B / (2.*math.pi)          # shape= [v,]

    r = M[..., np.newaxis] * b    

    return r                      # shape= [n, n, v]
```

the `...` elipses represent all the axes of array and `np.newaxis` adds a new axis, so together `A[..., np.newaxis]` returns an array of shape `[n, n, 1]` which can be broadcasted with `b`

broadcasting an array of shape `[n, n, 1]` with an array of shape `[v]` produces an array of shape `[n, n, v]`

if `A` were of shape `[a, b, c]`. `A[..., np.newaxis]` would have changed it to `[a, b, c, 1]`